# Crashing when an Intent is called inside a Recycler View Adapter

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-recyclerview

public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

```
holder.parentCard.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent=new Intent(context,DetailedView.class);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

The Intent is not passing to the other activity when the cardView is clicked.

Comment: You should use interface to get the callback in your activity and then you can do whatever you want in that callback instead of adapter and then send here the error if you get any.

Comment: Please add your logcat showing error, so users can view what is wrong with your code ? also share your code which shows " What is DetailsView.class" , is it activity, dialog, fragment , also share this code also.

Answer (score 0):

Recycler view doesnt have current activity context, so while recycler adapter initial time you need to pass current activity of context.
check context is null or not
check DetailedView activity registered manifest or not

another war to achieve intent interface concept is there
refer this tutorial better https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/android-recyclerview/

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple reasons to this crash since you have not provided the Crash logs/stacktrace.

1. The `context` provided is not an `Activity` context in which case you need to add the `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` or `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` to your Intent's flags.
2. It is possible the crash is in the `DetailedView` Activity due to probably a `NullPointerException` or it is not added to `AndroidManifest.xml`

Answer (score -1):

**This is not the right way.**

1. First of all crate interface callback

   public interface ItemClick {
   void onItemClick(int position);
   }
2. Then calling this interface method inside adapter class and passing through the constructor and finally

   itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
   if (settingsItemClick!=null)
   {
   int pos=getAdapterPosition();
   if(pos!=RecyclerView.NO_POSITION)
   {
   settingsItemClick.onItemClick(pos);
   }
   }
   }
   });

3.Then inside activity implements interface method.